# How to add different titles and subtitles to different Annotation points in a MapView?

Tags: iphone, ios5, maps, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I am displaying different annotation points in a mapview. I want to display different titles and subtitles for all the different annotations. I have my **viewForAnnotation** delegate method implemented in the below manner.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation;
{
    NSLog(@"annotation Class %@", [annotation class]);

if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[HGMovingAnnotation class]]) {

    static NSString *kMovingAnnotationViewId = @"HGMovingAnnotationView";

    HGMovingAnnotationView *annotationView = (HGMovingAnnotationView*)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:kMovingAnnotationViewId];

    if (!annotationView) {
        annotationView = [[HGMovingAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:kMovingAnnotationViewId];
    }

    //configure the annotation view
    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"symbol-moving-annotation.png"];

    annotationView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20); //initial bounds (default)
    annotationView.mapView = mapView;

    NSLog(@"Inside Moving Annotation");
    return annotationView;
}

static NSString *kCustomAnnotationView = @"CustomAnnotationView";

MKPinAnnotationView* customPinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:kCustomAnnotationView];

if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[CLLocation class]]) {
    MKAnnotationView *customAnnotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation
                                                                          reuseIdentifier:kCustomAnnotationView];
    customAnnotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"customAnnotation"];

    customAnnotationView.canShowCallout = NO;
    customAnnotationView.centerOffset = CGPointMake(2,-12);
    NSLog(@"Inside Custom Annotation1");
    return customAnnotationView;
} else {
    customPinView.annotation = annotation;
    customPinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
    NSLog(@"Inside Custom Annotation2");
    return customPinView;
}

}
```

I want to display the title and subTitle for the **customPinView** Annotations. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotation views do not have a title or subtitle. You need to subclass `MKAnnotation` and set the (sub)title on the custom annotation. The viewForAnnotation method is not the right place for this, you should call `[annotation setTitle:@"my title"]` right before `[mapView addAnnotation:annotation]`.

Sample code:

```
@interface MyCustomAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;
@property (nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the approach suggested by phix23 and came with the following code. It works..

```
titleArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"First Point",@"Second Point",@"Third Point",@"Fourth Point",@"Fifth Point", nil];
subTitleArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Restaurant",@"Park",@"Hotel",@"Theatre",@"AmusementPark", nil];

NSInteger customAnnotationCount = annotations.count;

//CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates[customAnnotationCount];

for (NSInteger index = 0; index < customAnnotationCount; index++) {

    CLLocation *location = [annotations objectAtIndex:index];
    NSString *titleString = [titleArray objectAtIndex:index];
    NSString *subTitleString = [subTitleArray objectAtIndex:index];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;
    //coordinates[index] = coordinate;
    CustomAnnotations *customAnnotation = [[CustomAnnotations alloc]initWithCoordinates:coordinate placeName:titleString description:subTitleString];
    [_mapView addAnnotation:customAnnotation];
    [customAnnotation release];
}
```

"annotations" is the array that contains Location points. _mapView is my MKMapView. CustomAnnotations is an NSObject Class implementing MKAnnotation protocol in the same way described on the top.